# wix install with customactions to edit file before service starts

Tags: wix

I have a project that creates an msi via a wix project.  This project has a customaction.  The customaction replaces values and encrypts passwords as part of the installation process.

My problem currently is that I cannot work out what what to put in the InstallExecuteSequence such that the installation has copied the files to the machine, but the service has not been started.  Is there a way to install files, edit the config and then start the service?

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
   <Custom Action="ConfigureDataAccess" Before="InstallServices" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I have tried After="InstallFinalize" After="InstallFiles"

The code either runs before the files have been copied, or after the service has started.

I am happy to work through guides or anything, but as yet haven't found any through googling.

Thanks